# Laravel 5.5 use custom validation rule in validation request file?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Is it possible to use my custom validation rule in a validation request file?

i want to use my custom rule called EmployeeMail
here is the code of the request file

```
class CoachRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [];

    if ($this->isMethod('post') ) {
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email|employeemail', <<<--- this
            'till' => 'required|date_format:H:i|after:from',
        ];
    }

    //TODO fix this
    //TODO add custom messages for every field

    return $rules;
}
}
```

it gives me an error when i try to use it like this

Method [validateEmployeemail] does not exist.

**code of custom rule**

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class EmployeeMail implements Rule
{
/**
 * Create a new rule instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Determine if the validation rule passes.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    // If mail is that of an employee and not a student pass it
    return preg_match("/@test.nl$/", $value) === 1;
}

/**
 * Get the validation error message.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function message()
{
    return 'Email is geen werknemers mail';
}
}
```

can i only use this custom rule like this?

```
$items = $request->validate([
    'name' => [new FiveCharacters],
]);
```

Comment: It seems you are validating string with a regular expression, the same logic can be achieved by regex buit-in validation method. Check it out. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-regex No need to create your own validation rule.

Comment: If you want to use your validation pass it into an array. like this. `'email' => ['required', 'email', new employeemail],`

Comment: @RutvijKothari Ah thanks, i will use the regex rule instead then, i forgot about it. and also thanks for mentioning how i would use a custom rule in request file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rutvij Kothari answered the question in the comments.

It seems you are validating string with a regular expression, the same logic can be achieved by regex buit-in validation method. Check it out. laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-regex No need to create your own validation rule. – Rutvij Kothari

If you want to use your validation pass it into an array. like this. 'email' => ['required', 'email', new employeemail]